# .NET equivalent for GetLastInputInfo?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a .NET equivalent to the Windows [`GetLastInputInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms646302.aspx) API?

I know it's possible to P/Invoke the API but I'm looking for a method or technique that's already built into the .NET framework.

Answer (score 10):

There isn't a direct translation of that specific API in the .NET BCL.  Fortunately, it's a [very easy method to P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo).

That being said, there are other ways to attempt to check user idle state.  Most still require P/Invoke at some level (at least all of the ones that handle other applications).

Here is a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uim.aspx) comparing options.

Comment: @Cocowalla The linked article shows various options, including completely managed means of monitoring input, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't another call for this Pinvoke.net provides a P/Invoke solution for this [call](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo) and necessary [struct](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/LASTINPUTINFO.html).