# Detecting idle users in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to pause my program if a user is inactive for 5 minutes. By inactive I mean hasn't pressed their mouse or their keyboard during that time (including outside the program too!). Any starting points?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within a timer you could p/invoke [`GetLastInputInfo()`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getlastinputinfo) which will return the number ms since input was detected from the user, across all processes in the current session.

Comment: Seems like what I need, but the weird thing is that LASTINPUTINFO only increases when I'm moving my mouse.

Comment: It returns the tick-time of the last input so it will go up, deduct it from Environment.TickCount

Answer (score 6):

This question is very similar to an old question:

[.NET equivalent for GetLastInputInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069910/net-equivalent-for-getlastinputinfo)

Which referenced a good article describing some different options in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uim.aspx

If you don't mind using P/Invoke and being limited to running on windows systems, then using P/Invoke to call GetLastInputInfo() is probably the simplest method of accomplishing what you want.

Answer (score 2):

you could override the WndProc and look for the WM_IDLE message

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [GMA.UserActivityMonitor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) library a while ago to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found solution for Your problem, look at:

**[How to detect a Winforms app has been idle for certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430850/how-to-detect-a-winforms-app-has-been-idle-for-certain-amount-of-time)**
and **user34660** answer,

For your app, must change:

```
const int MinuteMicroseconds = 60000;
```

to

```
const int MinuteMicroseconds = 300000;
```

It's just time, but in ms.

Works nice for my Windows Forms application.