# How to detect idle on monitor 2?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a TV hooked up to my laptop via HDMI all day/night. In the daytime, most of the time I just have a radio station on the TV. Essentially I'm trying to make a screensaver for just the TV, to prevent burn-in.

I currently have a SWF file with random shapes being made that I put on full-screen, but it's a case of remembering to put it on; and also, it's a little bit of a pain to get it off if I need to quickly demo something on the TV.

How can I detect if monitor #2 is idle for 5 mins? Then if the mouse moves to the TV, an event is fired.

The width of monitor #1 is 1366px, if the solution requires knowing the x pos of the mouse.

I don't really mind what language this is made in, but I'd prefer C#.

Comment: Use C# to Detect if the mouse is idle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282298/detecting-idle-users-in-winforms then when that happens, read: How to use C# to programatically turn on/off a monitor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor

Comment: Instead of add lots of language tags, it would be nicer to add a tag for the Operating System you are using...

Comment: @EricLeschinski Thanks, but it's detecting the idle time on a specific monitor that's the problem, not the turning the display off.

Comment: @Veger I've edited the tags, I'd prefer a C# solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the current cursor position via [`System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx). The simplest (but perhaps not best) approach would be to poll this periodically. If you have not seen the mouse move on that screen within a certain amount of time, you could launch the SWF. Also, when the mouse does move on that screen, you can close the SWF.

Comment: Thanks, that works great! `while (true) { if (Cursor.Position.X <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) MessageBox.Show("hi"); Thread.Sleep(100); }`