# Hide cursor when user is doing nothing

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I want to hide cursor in my application when user is doing nothing, like when you start watching movie on YT, after 10s cursor is hiding and if user is moving mouse or he clicked on keyboard then cursor is showing.
I know I should use

```
Cursor.Hide();
Cursor.Show();
```

but I don't know what method I should use for wait operation?

Comment: Not my choice, the SO engine thinks it does.  If you think it was wrong about it then surely you can convince it by typing more than a single paragraph of text and a nonsensical code snippet.

Comment: may you help me with this, exactly I don't know what can I change in my question @Hans

Comment: @HansPassant my question is in C# and those question what is compared with mine is in vb.net

Comment: @Jacek Are you using WPF or WindowsForms?

Comment: WindowsForms @PiotrChojnacki

Comment: @HansPassant Do you think SO needs people who can only follow it's recommendations regarding closing threads? Well, it doesn't. So, think first before you act. There's nothing wrong with a question, I'd rather say it's OK as it doesn't need more description.

Comment: @Jacek You should look at this thread, it's probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282298/detecting-idle-users-in-winforms

Comment: @Piotr - you linked the same answer I did.  Nice thinking. It wasn't enough so I removed the vote again.  Somebody needs to post the send-me-teh-codez answer, feel free to step up to the plate.