# Expressing the C# conditional, "if a mouse/keyboard action has not occurred in the last 'n' seconds"

Tags: c#, winforms, events, conditional-statements

The question is how to have a C# program (running in Windows) check to see whether or not a key button has been pressed, or the mouse has been moved/clicked, within a set amount of time in the past.

One solution I found uses the "KeyPress" event, but this only works if the control (or application) has focus.  I am seeking a solution that works even while the program is running in the background.

Additionally, it would be nice to have a way to exclude certain events (i.e., the key "Z") from the conditional.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting idle users in Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282298/detecting-idle-users-in-winforms)

Comment: It's a similar concept, but I'm really hoping to find something that can exclude certain specific keys.

Comment: Are you sure the CodePlex project referenced in the last answer wouldn't be useful for your situation (http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)? Seems like you could handle the system-wide mouse/keyboard events and simply ignore the ones you want.

Comment: If it needs to be selective then use Application.AddMessageFilter().

Answer (score 5):

There is a function in the WinAPI doing just that: [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302.aspx).

> This function is useful for input idle detection. However, GetLastInputInfo does not provide system-wide user input information across all running sessions. Rather, GetLastInputInfo provides session-specific user input information for only the session that invoked the function.

And there's even an [example on pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetLastInputInfo.html). Here's my version:

```
public static TimeSpan GetIdleTime()
{
    var lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO
    {
        cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO))
    };

    if (!GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
        throw new Win32Exception("GetLastInputInfo failed");

    return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount - lastInputInfo.dwTime);
}
```

Relevant P/Invoke definitions:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 cbSize;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwTime;
}
```

Comment: That return statement is a real doozy.  40 characters to avoid a division when the numerator is zero.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, and the fact the function doesn't return a `TimeSpan`... but I quoted it as-is from pinvoke.net. I'll improve that.

Comment: Thanks, that looks close to what I'm after, but it doesn't seem to return what the event in question actually was, if I understand it correctly.  I'd also need a way to check the second to last event, if the last event was an exception (i.e. for the question, "was there any non-Z-key input in the past 15 seconds?", if the last input was Z and occurred 1 second ago, I'd need to check the event before it).

Comment: @user10478 I thought it was in the *nice to have* category, but since you really need it, this solution won't cut it. You'll have to install systemwide hooks. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to write an anwser detailing this right now, sorry. I'll try tomorrow if no-one answers till then.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was my unclear way of saying I don't know for certain whether I'll need it (because my program will be outputting the equivalent of key presses, but only 4 specific keys).  Not sure if the output will interfere with GetLastInputInfo yet.